# How to manage Map<String,List<dynamic>> in Dart/Flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, dart, collections

I have a json response with maps with list of value pair for each keys in map. How can I manage this one?

```
JSON FORMAT,


{ABS: [Instance of 'Data', Instance of 'Data', Instance of 'Data', Instance of 'Data', Instance of 'Data', Instance of 'Data'], BSE: [Instance of 'Data'], CFO: [Instance of 'Data']}
```

Comment: Give the example of the json response

Comment: edited the question, please check

Comment: Instance of 'Data' ?? I think its not the actual response you get from server. Its parsed one. Validate your json at https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: yeah, its grouped by using the collection package.

Comment: I have the json response with duplicated heading names. I just grouped it by using the collection package in flutter and it shows three maps with value pair as list of objects. Here Data is my object

Comment: May be a raw response will be better to understand issue

Comment: Define "manage".